# Get a List of conffiles in a deb package in python

Tags: python, package, apt

I want to get the list of conffiles associated with a deb package using python. I am working on a project for which I need to know if any conffile installed by a package is modified so I need to have a list of conffiles installed by a package so that I can use it to see which of the conffile has been modified.

I tried to use  [python-apt library documentation](http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/index.html) , but could not find any method for doing that , Please suggest me a way of doing that. I know I can extract the control information and read the raw conffiles file but I think there might be a method in the library itself.

Comment: /var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.conffiles, yes not so much elegant but it works

Comment: Yes that's a method for getting a list of conffiles but it won't work for package that is yet to be installed. I thought there might be a much more elegant method in python-apt library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is tested on python-apt on squeeze:
the package I used is:

http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh-server_5.5p1-6+squeeze1_amd64.deb

```
from apt.debfile import DebPackage
ssh = DebPackage('openssh-server_5.5p1-6+squeeze1_amd64.deb')
print ssh.control_content('conffiles').split('\n')

[u'/etc/init.d/ssh', u'/etc/default/ssh', u'/etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server', u'/etc/ufw/applications.d/openssh-server', u'/etc/pam.d/sshd', u'']
```

you need to strip out the last one

```
print ssh.data_content('etc/init.d/ssh')
u'#! /bin/sh\n\n### BEGIN INIT INFO\n#......'
```

you need to strip out the first slash

Comment: What is the role of 'u'/etc/init.d/ssh\n/etc/default/ssh\n/etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server\n/etc/ufw/applications.d/openssh-server\n/etc/pam.d/sshd\n' ?
This code is not displaying conffiles list

Comment: ssh.control_content('conffiles').split('\n'), you'll have a list of conf files, control_content extract 'conffiles' file that is exactly a text file with the list of conf files one per line

Comment: Ok. I have marked your answer as answer but its still not working for me I trying to print the output of ssh,control_content('conffiles') , but it did not print anything could you suggest what should I do for that?

Comment: do you also need the content?

Comment: Yes indeed its working with your given deb file but not with my deb files,which I found because the packages don't contain conffiles file in control data. I have created packages using dpkg-repack , i thought it would pack conffiles also. doesn't it ?

Comment: Yes I need the content ie. those files also, Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Also could you suggest something that if I am using dpkg-repack for creating packages I am not getting the conffiles file in it , do you have an idea of an option through which I can do that ? That will be really very helpful.

Comment: squeeze version of dpkg-repack correctly adds conffiles in control, I've checked instead sid version and it uses dpkg-query -c, that does not include conffiles, so you may using a different version

Comment: Ok I am using ubuntu 11.10 or 10.04 I don't have squeeze. Do I need to install a different version or build from source ?

Comment: uudecode and apply this patch (I had to uuencode because of tabs) http://pastebin.com/U84KNCdX obviously on the next update of dpkg-repack this workaround gets lost, I think the bug should be filled on debian bug tracking system, my patch is only a workaround a different fix should be implemented

Answer (score 0):

The status flag

```
dpkg --status bash
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, But I needed to do this using python-apt library.